# How to insert the "move" icon into Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, icons, cursor, symbols

Is the "move" icon available in Microsoft Word?

[image: move icon]

Is there an alt code for it?

Comment: I did a bit of a search, including on my Microsoft Word (2010), I could not find that symbol - would be interested to see an answer to this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically, Word supports all Unicode characters. So if you can find the symbol [here](http://unicodelookup.com/#arrow), you could copy/paste it. I quickly glanced over the list but couldn't find it.

The font you use should also include a glyph for that particular symbol.

If you can't find the symbol you want, you can obviously paste the image you used above. Or use a custom font, as Fuzzy pointed out.

Comment: ↬ Thanks for pointing to this site! I found some nice unknown symbols, but not the move symbol. :(

Comment: I think i go than for the image paste. Because if you send the document to other people or print it, the icon could disappear. But let's wait a moment for someone else for a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

the windows charmap doesn't contain this symbol.
But you can simply use a special symbol font where's it included.
http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/3.2.1/icon/move/

So just download Font-Awesome
http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/

and install the "fontawesome-webfont.ttf" onto your computer. (You can find it in the zip-file subfolder fonts).

Afterwards chose "fontawesome" in Word and type the character "i".
Then you will get the desirered symbol...

Comment: Using fontistic tricks means that when text is copied and pasted as plain text, the magic symbols turn to various letters. The same happens when the document is converted to a different format, unless the receiving program happens to have the same font available.

Answer (score 1):

I found another solution. It's maybe not the best, but maybe for some people it could be useful.
First i created a textarea. Than i pasted ↔ and ↕. 
Then i go to advanced font settings, and adjust the letter distance so the two symbols are stacked up together.

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a cursor and comes from the corresponding [CUR file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICO_%28file_format%29) in the directory

> C:\Windows\Cursors

The variants of this particular cursor are located in files with names "move_*.cur" in that directory. Word does not allow to import a .CUR file directly but you can open such file in IrfanView, save as PNG and then insert the image in a Word document.